# Boot Camp 6 upgrade not offered in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp

I have a mid-2013 MacBook Air which was running Windows 8.1 under Boot Camp 5, and I upgraded the OS to Windows 10. While mostly it works fine some things (like keyboard support) seem to have some issues.

Apple have released Boot Camp 6 which supports Windows 10, and apparently my model is on the [supported list](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204990), and yet the Apple Software Update tool never finds Boot Camp 6 as being available for download.

Is there any way to force the Software Update tool to find and offer Boot Camp 6? Apple don't seem to have made a direct link available to download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from that page - "This software is automatically downloaded when you use Boot Camp Assistant."
..or you upgraded to Win10 before Boot Camp 6 was available?

Extract from the [page you linked](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204990) (renumbered)...

> 1. Start your Mac from the version of Windows you currently have installed.
> 2. Open Apple Software Update for Windows and install available updates, including the FaceTime Camera Update.
> 3. Use the Windows installer to upgrade Windows.
> 4. After installation is complete, open Apple Software Update for Windows again and install available updates to make sure the Windows Support Software (drivers) for Boot Camp are up to date. As part of driver installation, your Mac might restart one or more times.
>
> After driver installation is complete, log in to Windows to begin using Windows 10 on your Mac.

Comment: I upgraded before Boot Camp 6 was available, so it's not clear that these steps can be done now without damaging the Windows installation.

Comment: the first checkbox in Boot Camp Assistant is "download the latest drivers". You need a 2GB FAT32 USB stick.

Comment: So I run BCA under OSX and set up a USB stick with the drivers, ok - but I already have Windows 10 installed. How would I get it to update using the drivers on the USB stick?

Comment: run the setup.exe from in Windows